# How to know the parent block of an item in memory allocator

Tags: c++, memory-management, memory-pool

I am designing a custom memory allocator that manages a pool of large blocks each containing a fixed number of items.

```cpp
using T = ItemType;

struct Block {
  char data[M*sizeof(T)];  // M is tunable, power of two or else
  int i {0};
  Freelist freelist;
  // ... other data field
}

// Pool collects a number of pooled blocks
struct Pool {
  std::list<Block> blocks;  
  // other data field
}
```

The `allocate` will allocate one item of uninitialized memory from an available block. Due to application, my `allocate` need to handle one item at a time. The size in bytes of the item is `sizeof(T)`.

```cpp
T* allocate() {
  Block b* = pool.get_one_block();
  int idx = b->get_free_index();
  return reinterpret_cast<T*>(b->data) + idx;
}
```

The `deallocate` takes an item pointer `ptr` and recycle it to the allocator. Before any internal processing, we need to know the item's `block`. **How do I do this without asking `T` to include additional satellite pointer to its original block?**

```cpp
void deallocate(T* ptr) {
  Block* b = how_to_get_the_block_of_ptr();  // <-- is there any faster way to do so?
  b->add_free_list(ptr);
  // other internal processing
}
```

I heard there are some bitwise tricks together with aligned memory allocation to retrieve the block of a pointer in designing a memory allocator. Help needs.

Comment: There are a few ways to do this, memory allocation, particularly fast memory allocation, is a hard task. But testing a pointer exist in a block of memory is easy, something like. `if(ptr >= mem_block_start && ptr < mem_block_start + mem_block_size)` might do the trick.

Comment: As for alignment, look into std::alignment_of template function. As well as std::align.

Comment: how to you know `mem_block_start` in `deallocate(T* ptr)`? This is the question

Comment: Your `Pool` has a list of blocks in it.  Iterate thru that list until you find the block that contains the pointer.